# In linked list formation, what is the code for adding a variable at the beginning?

Tags: c++, linked-list

I am trying to add and print a new node at the beginning of my linked list. But my code doesn't show the added data while printing in C++.

```
struct node{
    int data;
    node *next;
};
void add_begin(node *S, int k)
{
    node *T;
    T=new (node);
    T->data=k;
    T->next=S;
    S=T;
}
void print(node *S)
{
    cout<<"Elements of the node :\n";
    while (S->next!=NULL)
    {
        cout<<S->data<<endl;
        S=S->next;
    }
    cout<<S->data<<endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that you would be calling this function passing in a `node` which is the head of a list and an `int` which is the new data and are expecting the node you passed in to be updated to the new node.

Unfortunately that is not what is happening. Inside the function `add_begin` it has its own pointer to the first node in the list so when you update it with `S=T` only pointer in the function is updated, not the one you passed in as well.

If you want to update the pointer you pass in you should pass it by reference (`void add_begin(node *&S, int k)`) or return the new node pointer from the function and assign it the external pointer manually.

Comment: +1 The latter option (returing the new head pointer and relying on the *caller* to overwrite the old one) is considerably *less desirable*, as it puts the onus on the caller to perform what the linked list functional api should be doing: managing node pointers. It is not uncommon to see this in-practice in academia-based linked list code, unfortunately.